# Architecture: Grouping client side, or pulling multiple grouped data from server?

Tags: javascript, mysql

*(I hope this question is not opinionated, cause I do feel there is a right and wrong answer, so if it is just tell me and I will delete it)*

I have data in a MySQL database with a field that contains a few different values, but needs to be grouped according to these values (I know what the values are). So my question is:

- Is it better to pull all the data from the server at once (because all the data WILL be used), and then on the client side via JS to sort the data into the groups based on the field that you want.
- Or is it better to make multiple small request to the server, getting only the data that matches a single field, and then using that data directly in the program.

I would think that the main consideration would be to have as few people spend time on the server, since client side work is much more efficient (faster and only one user) compared to server side (internet connections are slower, and there are many more users).

But what works out faster and better: Many small server requests, or one large server request.

So example:

```
   Name:       Group

    Alpha:     Top
    Bravo:     Top
    Delta:     Bottom
    Charlie:   Top
    Echo:      Bottom
    Fox:       Bottom
    Gama:      Bottom
    Hotel:     Top
    India:     Top
    Juliet:    Bottom
```

Is it better to get all the data from the server with one query (`$sql = "Select * FROM table";`), and then use a client side function to group the data (`GroupBy(data,groups){};`)

Or to make two database queries (`$sql = "Select * FROM database where group = $group";`), and then just use the data as it comes in already grouped?

A real world example would be like Amazon, where there will be allot of queries by a user every day, but they may be searching for shoes, so do you get the data, price and description of the shoes all at once via an API request, and then group it server side and put it into columns, or do you first get all the sizes, then color, then look and just insert every request into a column?

Comment: If data is small, don't focus too much about it. Sorting and grouping is relatively cheap operation if you indexed table correctly.

Comment: HI, thank you for your answer, the data will actually now be that large, but the users will be MANY...

Comment: I would recommend split that into small parts and let client request when they need (don't give all the data at the same time). because it's easy to cache, flexible to data schema change, faster delivery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance in databases is always one of those big issues. I don't think there is correct answer for this because what works best for you depends on many things. If this is going to be a process that takes the data, for example, once a day, I would go for taking the data gradually in batches. The size of the batch depends on your server, on how big the database is, etc. I would personally try with different sizes and I would monitor the server to see how it goes.

If this is one of those once in a time (because maybe you are doing a migration), you might be ok taking all the data at once. But this also depends in case you have an SLA for the migration, how long it takes the MySQL to return the whole set of data, etc.

Take also into account, that even if you work on a batch size that is perfect for you right now, it might not be like that in the future depending on how much the database grows.

I think that the best answer for this would be: try different approaches (all the data, by groups or by batch size), monitor the server, and chose the one that applies best for you.

Hope this helps you with your question.

Comment: Thank you, I think the fact that a person should not be set on one dogma is probably the right way to go. But I maybe should have added that the data would be almost something like, lets say Amazon, where there will be allot of queries by a user every day, but they may be searching for shoes, do you get the data, price and description of the shoes all at once, and then group it and put it into columns, or do you first get all the the sizes, then color, then look and insert every request into a column...

Comment: I think I would go for small requests assuming your database is big (or that it will grow). They run faster and are easier to handle. If you have all big SELECTS all over it will be impossible to reduce something into an INDEX SEEK on the execution plan and you will be constantly SCANNING the indexes or tables. Besides, if you take all the data and send it to the client, how would you handle a situation where a product was updated? You would need to refresh the client and make the same big request again.

Comment: Thanks, you have the same answers and make some good point that I did not think about!